# How Spring's ResolvableType resolves generics while java compiler does type erasure?

Tags: spring, autowired, type-erasure

We know in Java that generic types are for compile time only and because of type erasure we will not have this generic type parameter info at runtime.

But I came across Spring's `ResolvableType` which is able to resolve generic type parameter at runtime and because of this capability Spring can autowire even parameterized Lists.

So how `ResolvableType` getting access to Type param info?

Ref:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire-generics

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html